# C++: Remove repeated numbers in a matrix

Tags: c++, coordinates

I want to remove numbers from a matrix that represents coordinates with the format 'x y z'. One example:

```
1.211 1.647 1.041

2.144 2.684 1.548

1.657 2.245 1.021

1.657 0.984 2.347

2.154 0.347 2.472

1.211 1.647 1.041
```

In this example the coordinates 1 and 6 are the same (x, y and z are the same) and I want to remove them but I do not want to remove cases with only one value equal as coordinates 3 and 4 for x-coordinate).

These values are in a text file and I want to print the coordinates without duplication in another file or even in the same one.

Comment: Careful with floating-point numbers and equality tests...

Comment: In addition to @Jubobs comment, I suggest removing points that are a within a given distance from the point, in the L^2 norm.

Comment: Are you allowed to manipulate the order of the coordinates, for example by sorting them? Are they guaranteed to always be three numbers below 10, with three digits following the decimal?

Comment: I give a +1 to Erik and Jubobs. As output you intend to have only the five first lines? You just want to remove the duplicated coordinates ?

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution would be to treat each line as a string and use a set of strings. As you traverse the file line-wise, you check if the current line exists in the set and if not, you insert and print it.
Complexity: O(nlogn), extra memory needed: almost the same as your input file in the worst case

With the same complexity and exactly the worst case memory consumption as the previous solution, you can load the file in memory, sort it line-wise, and then easily skip duplicates while printing. The same can be done inside the file if you are allowed to re-order it, and this way you need very little extra memory, but be much slower.

If memory and storage is an issue (I'm assuming since you can't duplicate the file), you can use the simple method of comparing the current line with all previous lines before printing, with O(n^2) complexity but no extra memory. This however is a rather bad solution, since you have to read multiple times from the file, which can be really slow compared to the main memory.

Answer (score 1):

How to do this if you want to preserve the order.

1. Read the coordinates into an array of structures like this

   ```
   struct Coord
   { 
     double x,y,z; 
     int pos;
     bool deleted;
   };
   ```

   pos is the line number, deleted is set to false.
2. Sort the structs by whatever axis tends to show the greatest variation.
3. Run through the array comparing the value of the axis you were using in the sort from the previous item to the value in the current item. If the difference is less than a certain preset delta (.i.e. if you care about three digits after the decimal point you would look for a difference of 0.000999999 or so) you compare the remaining values and set deleted for any line where x,y,z are close enough.

   ```
   for(int i=1;i<count;i++)
   {
     if(fabs(arr[i].x-arr[i-1].x)<0.001)
       if(fabs(arr[i].y-arr[i-1].y)<0.001)
         if(fabs(arr[i].z-arr[i-1].z)<0.001)
           arr[i].deleted=true;
   }
   ```
4. sort the array again, this time ascending by pos to restore the order.
5. Go through the array and output all items where deleted is false.

Answer (score 0):

In c++, you can use the the power of STL to solve this problem. Use the [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) and store the three coordinates x, y and z as a key in the map. The mapped value to the key will store the count of that key.

```
Key_type = pair<pair<float,float>,float>
mapped_type = int
```

Create a map m with the above given key_type and mapped_type and insert all the rows into the map updating the count for each row. Let's assume n is the total number of rows.

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        m[make_pair(make_pair(x,y),z)]++;
}
```

Each insertion takes O(logn) and you have to insert n times. So,overall time complexity will be O(nlogn). Now, loop over all the rows of the matrix again and if the mapped_value of that row is 1, then it is unique.